# How to handle multiple queries in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to handle nested queries using gorm and I am having troudble figuring this out.

The queries:

```
SELECT smId AS 'slimeId', slStatus, slPPIV, slHighRiskSituation, 
(SELECT count(rnIg) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'Holding on'
AND rnSmId = smId) AS 'holdingOn',
(SELECT count(rnIg) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'In system' AND rnSmId = smId)
 AS 'inSystem', smSuspectedCorona,
IF(smStatusClosed != 0, 1, 0) as statusClosed, smSurge, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rnName) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'Holding on' AND rnSmId = smId) 
as 'ruinsOnHold',
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rnName) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'In system' AND rnSmId = smId)
as 'ruinsInSystem' FROM slimes WHERE slId != 0  GROUP BY slId HAVING slId > 0
```

So I can get some of it done which is pretty basics, the problem is when nesting comes which I don't know what to do in that case

```
var data []SlimeResponse
db := service.gormdb
db = db.Select("smId as slimeId", "slStatus", "slPPIV", "slHighRiskSituation")
db = db.Where("smId != ?", 0).Group("smId ").Having("smId > ?", 0)
db = db.Table("slimes").Find(&data)
```

Tried using `Where` method but didn't work same as `Joins` but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subQuery`](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#SubQuery)

```golang
var data []SlimeResponse
db := service.gormdb
subQueryHoldingOn := db.
  Select("count(rnIg)").
  Where("rnSquidStatus = 'In system' AND rnSmId = ?", smId).
  Table("ruins")
subQueryInSystem := db.
  Select("count(rnIg)").
  Where("rnSquidStatus = 'Holding on' AND rnSmId = ?", smId).
  Table("ruins")
groupSubQueryHoldingOn := db.
  Select("GROUP_CONCAT(rnIg)").
  Where("rnSquidStatus = 'In system' AND rnSmId = ?", smId).
  Table("ruins")
groupSubQueryInSystem := db.
  Select("GROUP_CONCAT(rnIg)").
  Where("rnSquidStatus = 'Holding on' AND rnSmId = ?", smId).
  Table("ruins")
db = db.Select("smId as slimeId, slStatus, slPPIV, slHighRiskSituation, (?) as holdingOn, (?) as inSystem, smSuspectedCorona, IF(smStatusClosed != 0, 1, 0) as statusClosed, smSurge, (?) as ruinsOnHold, (?) as ruinsInSystem", subQueryHoldingOn, subQueryInSystem, groupSubQueryHoldingOn, groupSubQueryInSystem)
db = db.Where("smId != ?", 0).Group("smId ").Having("smId > ?", 0)
db = db.Table("slimes").Find(&data)
```

Or

You can directly pass the select part in [`Select`](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Selecting-Specific-Fields)

```golang
var data []SlimeResponse
db := service.gormdb
db = db.Select(
  `
    smId AS 'slimeId',
    slStatus,
    slPPIV,
    slHighRiskSituation, 
    (
      SELECT count(rnIg) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'Holding on' AND rnSmId = ?
    ) AS 'holdingOn',
    (
      SELECT count(rnIg) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'In system' AND rnSmId = ?
    ) AS 'inSystem',
    smSuspectedCorona,
    IF(smStatusClosed != 0, 1, 0) as statusClosed,
    smSurge, 
    (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rnName) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'Holding on' AND rnSmId = ?
    ) as 'ruinsOnHold',
    (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rnName) FROM ruins WHERE rnSquidStatus = 'In system' AND rnSmId = ?
    ) as 'ruinsInSystem'
  `, smId, smId, smId, smId
)
db = db.Where("smId != ?", 0).Group("smId ").Having("smId > ?", 0)
db = db.Table("slimes").Find(&data)
```